# O que esta errado na variavel double

Tags: c, c++

Preciso fazer um algoritmo que o usuario informa dois valores e retornar o maior entre eles usando double, mas na  hora  de compilar ele da erro apontando algo no double mas nao sei como resolver, alguem pode me ajudar e me explicar como utilizaria corretamente?

```
#include <stdio.h>
double maior(double *x, double *y)    
{  
    double maior;   

    if (*x>*y)
    {
        maior=*x;
        return maior;
    }

    else
    {
        maior=*y;
    }

    return maior;
}



int main()  
{   

    double x,y,m;

    printf("Informe dois valores com espaco entre eles:");
    scanf("%f %f",&x,&y);

    m=maior(&x,&y);

    printf("O maior eh: %f \n",m);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: E no ultimo `printf` o `printf("O maior eh: \n",m);` faltou o formatador para o `m`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema que está acontecendo se deve ao fato de que você está tentando retornar uma variável do tipo **double** em um função que supostamente **deveria** retornar um **int**. Para retornar o double, troque o tipo de retorno da função para double:

```
double maior(double *x, double *y) {  
    double m;   

    if (*x>*y)
    {
        m=*x;
        return m;
    }

    else
    {
        m=*y;
    }

    return m;
}

printf("O maior é: %f\n", m); // Faltou o formatador
```

Apenas acrescentando, sua função poderia ser reduzida para o seguinte código:

```
double maior(double x, double y) {
    if(x < y)
        return y;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: `return x < y ? y : x;`.

Comment: Eu fiz isso , porem continua dando erro na compilação falando "warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double *’ [-Wformat=]
  scanf("%f %f",&x,&y);" o que pode ser?

Comment: @flavio Use `maior(x, y)` ao invés de `maior(&x, &y)`.

Comment: @VictorStafusa sou obrigado  a  passar por referencia o valor de x e y no programa, o problema e q n ta compilando ele

Comment: @flavio `scanf("%lf %lf", &x, &y);` - O `%lf` é para `double` enquanto que o `%f` é para `float`.

Comment: deu certo agora @VictorStafusa, precisava do lf, vlw mano